# Rcpp Segmentation Fault in module after updating R version

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am in the process of building an R package using C++ code. I recently updated my macOS to Big Sur (v 11.4) which forced me to update R to a 64-bit version. In particular, I'm using R version 4.1.0 and Rcpp 1.0.6. Prior to the update, I had no issues creating modules from my C++ classes. I was able to successfully create module pointers in R that I was able to pass back to C++ functions.
Now, when working with the same code I was before, I get a segmentation fault when constructing these pointers. The error message is below.

```
Loading required package: Rcpp

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: Module(module, mustStart = TRUE)
 2: .getModulePointer(x)
 3: la_module$LocatingArray
 4: la_module$LocatingArray
 5: LocatingArrayTools::buildModels(la_path = path, factor_data_path = factor_data,     response_dir = response, response_column = "binding")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm not sure all of what will help to help my problem, but I'll provide the snip-it of the R code that is actually causing this issue.

```
##load la module and make local la
  la_module <- Module("LocatingArray_module")
  LocatingArray <- la_module$LocatingArray
  la_local <- new(LocatingArray, la_path, factor_data_path)
  ##get tests for response vector
  tests = la_local$getTests()
  
  ##make pointer to la object to pass to csmatrix
  la <- LocatingArrayTools::LocatingArray__new(la_path, factor_data_path)
```

I would be more than happy to provide any additional information but I didn't want to make this original post too long. I didn't see anyone else who has had this issue this year so I'm hoping that someone can offer some suggestions.

The GitHub repo for the full code is here: https://github.com/leahdarwin/LocatingArrayTools

Actually providing the files and commands to reproduce the code is some additional work, but I can provide if needed. Thank you!

Comment: A warm welcome to StackOverflow. I doubt anybody can help you with the question as it currently stands -- it is generally advisable to post [minimally complete and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In general, Rcpp and Rcpp Modules work just fine on all macOS versions, and we have various packages at CRAN that demonstrate it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi Dr. Eddelbuettel, I appreciate your quick reply. As you guessed, I really was not sure how to present this problem. I'll try to get it into a reproducible example but my error feels so wrapped up in my package I'm not sure where to start. I'll repost in the future when I figure something out.

Comment: Sounds good. When confronted with something that "should work" or "works in other cases" I often check if packages with a similar structure build.  For that, you could look for example at `RcppAnnoy` which also uses Rcpp Modules. If it builds and installs fine you may have crossed a wire in your package.  Also: first things first.  If your package depends on any other package, make that package (incl Rcpp) is rebuilt correctly from source.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the advice, I'll try that first. This is my first time trying my hand at package development so I was completely lost on where to start. I really think it's cool how active you are in helping those with your Rcpp package!

Comment: Every long journey starts with a first step. Take your time and remember that everybody you meet was a beginner at what they do now at some point too.